# boto3 RDS get all Database names of a DB instance

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, boto3

I have 2 database name of MySQL Aurora for same host, username and password.
Like Below

```
{"host": "aaaa....rds.amazonaws.com"  , "username": "test", "password": "test", "database": "db1" }
```

Similarly

```
{"host": "aaaa....rds.amazonaws.com"  , "username": "test", "password": "test", "database": "db2" }
```

But I can not find the second database name while I am trying to access rds database instances by using boto 3 as stated below

```
 rds.describe_db_instances()['DBInstances']
```

It only return db1 not the db2

Can any one help me where and how can I find db2

Comment: That data isn't exposed via the AWS API, so you can't obtain that via boto3.

Comment: @Mark B Thank you for your comment Mark Can you tell me how can I get it ?

Comment: You have to make a connection to the MySQL database and query it directly.